# How I can convert any object (eg array) in json and get in the format string? In android

Tags: android, arrays, json

How I can convert any object (eg array) in json and get in the format string?
For example:

```
public String jsonEncode(Object obj) {
return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to convert any serializable objects into json String.

Here is the Tutorial [how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Comment: +1 GSON is definitely the easiest way to convert arbitrary objects to and from JSON objects/strings

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to do generic object serialization into json format in java, use reflection. Luckily, lots of the work is done for you, for example [this](http://code.google.com/p/jsonbeans) or [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

If you want to go the other way, or specificially you want more control over your serialization, you can still use reflection with annotations. See the [jackson mapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Hashtable<String, String> capitales = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        capitales.put("España", "Madrid");
        capitales.put("Francia", "Paris");
String miStringArray[] = { "String1", "String2" };
```

And I do:

```
SONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("name", "Jack Hack");
            obj.put("score", miStringArray);
            obj.put("otracosa", capitales );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(obj);
```

Show:

```
{"score":"[Ljava.lang.String;@413587d0","otracosa":"{Portugal=Lisboa, Francia=Paris, Argentina=Buenos Aires, España=Madrid}","name":"Jack Hack"}
```

Comment: Why did you posted this as answer..?instead you can edit your Question and paste there..And Check my answer..